# Prevent VueJS updated lifecycle when global variable is updated

Tags: nuxt.js, lifecycle

I am working on a dynamic menu for a new website. This menu is split up in a 3x3 pattern. 3 vertical rows and inside those rows can be a maximum of 3 horizontal blocks of content. These horizontal blocks have an integer linked in the database which can be 1, 2 or 3. The counted values of these horizontal blocks cannot be above 3, or else the next block won't be loaded in. A shorthanded explanation of the data I'm trying to load in.

This is the Javascript code I'm using for the function

```
countMenu(bool, count) {
  if(bool === true) {
    this.countWidth = count;    
  } else {
    this.countWidth += count;
  }

  window.console.log(this.countWidth);
  if(this.countWidth > 3) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true;
  }
},
```

The variable this.countWidth is defined in the data function. Once this variable is changed, I enter a infinite loop which keeps resetting the parent loop of defining the countWidth function. This happends because of the updated lifecycle if I'm correct.

My question is: Are you able to prevent the updated lifecycle from happening when a variable is changed? Or do we have to workaround for this variable?

My skills in Vue are quite limited. Thank you for reading the question.

Edit:

This is the entire html im using so far

```
<div
v-for="(menuItem, index) in desktopMenu.panelData"
:key = "index">
<ul
    v-if="
        desktopMenu.panelData[(index > 0) ? (index - 1) : index].verticale_sectie < 
        desktopMenu.panelData[index].verticale_sectie || 
        index == 1
    "
    :class="'h-'+desktopMenu.panelData[index].verticale_sectie+'/3 w-full'"
    style="border:1px solid black; "
>

    <li 
        v-if="countWidth(true, menuItem.horizontale_kolom)"
        :class="'w-'+menuItem.horizontale_kolom+'/3 h-full'"
        style="border:1px solid red; "
    >
        <span v-html="menuItem.html"></span> 
    </li>
</ul>
<li v-else-if="countWidth((index == 1) ? true : false, menuItem.horizontale_kolom) <= 3"
    :class="'w-'+menuItem.horizontale_kolom+'/3 h-full'"
    style="border:1px solid red; "
>
    <span v-html="menuItem.html"></span> 
</li> -->
```

Comment: It's hard to tell just from that snippet. Are you able to post your whole component?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: hi Michael, the function countMenu is not in the template.

Comment: Michal, can you elaborate what you said? I don't really get it..

Comment: Just assumptions. You should update your question even more as it is not clear. For example `countWidth` is used as a function from template but inside `countMenu` it is used as a property. Also the content of `countWidth` is missing...

Comment: You still haven't shown where countWidth is defined or countMenu is used.

Comment: You should not fight against the lifecycle but use it properly to match what you're trying to achieve. Reactivity is a good thing and it's better to not start hacking it from the beginning. Also, code highlight is always preferred for code snippets.